# display the number of entries created in the query if you only have the first and last entries (the entries have a letter)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-apex

This is my second question on this topic, I have not been able to solve this question for a long time, and I write again I have code with which you can create records in the range from the first to the last (this code in the first and the last entry is the first letters, and all subsequent letter symbols). To do this, I only need to specify the first and last entries. Here is the answer code and photo( I said the first number A14602157 and the last A14602167. (10 entries) in response to the query would be:):

```html
SELECT    SUBSTR (:P5_FIRST_SEALS, 1, 1) ||
          LPAD(TO_CHAR (  TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P5_FIRST_SEALS, '\d+$')) + level - 1), 8,'0') 
          AS x_SEAL_NUMBER
     FROM dual
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                TO_NUMBER (
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P5_LAST_SEALS, '\d+$'))
             - TO_NUMBER (
                   REGEXP_SUBSTR (:P5_FIRST_SEALS, '\d+$'))
             + 1;
```

[image]

After I find what records I need to make, I write a log in the table, where I specify the first record, the last record, and the date. Here's how I get data from the log table:

```html
SELECT      FIRST_SEALS,    LAST_SEALS,DATE from SEC_TRANSFER_SEALS
```

Is it possible to make this query in such a way that not only the first and last record of the range and the number of added records appear? I would like the answer to the second request to be this :

```html
SELECT      FIRST_SEALS,    LAST_SEALS,DATE , count(FIRST_SEALS between LAST_SEALS)  from SEC_TRANSFER_SEALS
```

```html
A14602157 , A14602167 , 07-06-21 , 10
```

Comment: I really don't understand your question. Are you generating those "seals" on the fly, or are you saving those in a table? Please provide the table structure, because based on your generator data, it's just that: `select min(x_seal_number), max(x_seal_number), count(x_seal_number)
from sec_transfer_seals`

Comment: @ThomasTschernich  thanks for responding, but I resolved this issue